# Do I have to set the same SecurityMode on WCF Client and Server?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

Depending on a user set value I change the NetTcpBinding SecurityMode property at the wcf client.

Do I have to set the same on the server? So for example on both sides The binding has securitymode "Transport".

What if the server has SecurityMode.None set, will the response be unencrypted then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security setting must be the same on both sides. Otherwise client will either not be able to connect to the server or security will not be used at all. In case of `NetTcpBinding` I expect first case to happen.

Comment: you were right! How can I dynamically set the Security mode when my nettcpbinding is set in c# code on the client and on the server my binding is defined in the app.config? How can change the server`s app.config from the client?

Comment: @Elisa your comment should be a new question methinks.

Comment: You don't `change the server's app.config from the client`. You decide on a minimum acceptable security setting at the server and set that in app.config. Then you make sure the client meets the server's requirements. And for testing what happens in various scenarios of client matching/not matching server, you...test.